# Add-Migration command for Entity Framework 7 not working for ASP.NET 5 class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I created an ASP.NET 5 class library with the following dependencies

```
"EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
```

I created my model and DatabaseContext classes. Now I want to add a migration so that I can create the database. By calling

```
dnx ef Add-Migration InitialMigration
```

from the commandline which is giving me the following error message

> System.InvalidOperationException: The current runtime target framework
>   is not compatible with 'Yugasat.Test'. Current runtime target
>   framework: 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1 (dnx451)'  Version:
>   1.0.0-rc1-16231  Type:         Clr  Architecture: x86  OS Name:      Windows  OS Version:   10.0  Runtime Id:   win10-x86
>
> Please make sure the runtime matches a framework specified in
>   project.json    at
>   Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.DefaultHost.GetEntryPoint(String
>   applicationName)    at
>   Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain(DefaultHost host,
>   String applicationName, String[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly
>   assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)    at
>   Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Bootstrapper.RunAsync(List`1 args,
>   IRuntimeEnvironment env, String appBase, FrameworkName
>   targetFramework)    at
>   Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.ExecuteAsync(String[] args,
>   BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)    at
>   Microsoft.Dnx.Host.RuntimeBootstrapper.Execute(String[] args,
>   BootstrapperContext bootstrapperContext)

As far as I can see from the error message my dnx version is 4.5.1 and the framework in my projects.json file is set to 4.5.1

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "description": "Yugasat.Test Class Library",
    "authors": [ "AndreL" ],
    "tags": [ "" ],
    "projectUrl": "",
    "licenseUrl": "",
    "frameworks": {
        "net451": {
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
      "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
      "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
      "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
   },
   "commands": {
       "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"frameworks": {
    "net451": {}
}
```

You need to use `dnx451` here, not `net451`. Then, the current runtime target framework (which is `DNX,Version=v4.5.1 (dnx451)`) will pick it up correctly.

Also note that the correct command is `dnx ef migrations add InitialMigration`; I’m not sure if the `Add-Migration` works.

Comment: Reading is an art as they say. Totally missed that, thank you.